# Flutter iOS Release Mode Error: Unrecognized Selector Exception and App Crash

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am encountering an error in Flutter iOS when running the app in release mode. The issue does not occur in debug mode. The error message indicates an "Unrecognized Selector Exception" that leads to an app crash.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[NSNull addSnapshotListenerWithIncludeMetadataChanges:listener:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f7deec48
```

the error only occurs in release mode and not in debug mode.

I have thoroughly searched for a solution, but have been unable to find a specific resolution for this issue. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this error and prevent the app from crashing in release mode.